# Исключить вывод определенной записи при запросе MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть сетка из изображений которые загрузили пользователи. При клике по изображению открывается отдельная страница, которая получает - `{$_GET['img']}`, чтобы определить по `ID` изображения автора загрузки. Первый запрос определяет `ID` пользователя, который загрузил изображение отображаемое на странице. Второй запрос выводит другие случайные 4 изображения который загрузил этот же пользователь.

Как исключить из второго запроса вывод изображения которое мы принимает методом - `{$_GET['img']}`? Так как нет смысла выводит то же самое изображение еще раз.

```
$reslt = mysql_query("SELECT users.id FROM images,users WHERE images.user_id_fk = users.id AND images.id={$_GET['img']}");
$arry = mysql_fetch_assoc($reslt);
$reslt2 = mysql_query("SELECT images.id,images.image_name FROM images,users WHERE images.user_id_fk = users.id AND users.id={$arry[id]} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
while($arry2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($reslt2))
```

Comment: `SELECT images.id,images.image_name FROM images,users WHERE images.user_id_fk = users.id AND users.id={$arry[id]} AND images.id !=  {$_GET['img']} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4`? так? Просто добавить еще одно условие `images.id !=  {$_GET['img']}`

Comment: @Manitikyl Да, я делал несколько не так и не получалось. Спасибо большое. Может вы вынесите это в ответ, чтобы я мог отметить решение?

Comment: Без проблем))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT images.id,images.image_name
FROM images,users
WHERE images.user_id_fk = users.id AND users.id={$arry[id]} AND images.id != {$_GET['img']}
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Просто добавить еще одно условие `... AND images.id != {$_GET['img']} ...`